# Is ruby's rand method supposed to accept Range objects?

Tags: ruby, random, jruby, range

I've only seen something like `rand(1..5)` work in MRI ruby 1.9.3 (haven't tried 1.9.2). Jruby doesn't support it, even in 1.9 mode - it raises a TypeError.

Even ruby-doc doesn't mention that Ranges are supported. What's the official behavior?

UPDATE

Well as the answers and comments point out, only 1.9.3 supports it. Jruby is only at 1.9.2.

Comment: also TypeError with "standard" ruby 1.9.2

Comment: tried using different versions of ruby via rvm. It seems to work only in the case of 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) *do* say that it is supported

> If max is Range, returns a pseudorandom number where range.member(number) == true.

It's also in the 1.9.3 [changelog](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_3_0/ChangeLog)

Comment: Ha, silly me for not actually reading the method description. I just looked at the argument name and default value `(max=0)`. I'll accept this once SO lets me.

Comment: Seems to be new, the [1.9.2 docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) don't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Verbatim Copy-paste from [docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/rand)

```
If max is Range, returns a pseudorandom number where range.member(number) == true.
Or else converts max to an integer using max1 = max.to_i.abs.
```

so, yes. it is supported from ruby 1.9.3

Comment: @Kelvin Sure, go ahead. I don't care about silly points. if any of my answers helped a soul on this plannet. that's good enough reason for me to keep doing posting more answers #JustSaying :)